# Quantity Increments in advanced inventory is not working for configurable products Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, inventory, multi-source-inventory

I tried to increment the product quantity by 10 steps on each click on the + sign by configuring it in the quantity increment from the advanced inventory of the product dashboard. Unfortunately, it is still incrementing 1 not 10 on one click. Someone, please help me to configure this properly. I don't understand if I am doing something wrong.

[image]